# Oracle OCI : Error messages when executing Rest API to get buckets list

Tags: java, rest, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I'm running the following Rest API in order to list our buckets:

```
https://objectstorage.{{MYREGION}}.oraclecloud.com/20160918/n/{{TENANCY}}/b/{{BUCKETNAME}}/o
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Illegal character in path at index 88: https://objectstorage.{{MYREGION}}.oraclecloud.com/20160918/n/{{TENANCY}}/b/{{BUCKETNAME}}/o
```

Why is that?

I couldn't find any reference on that on Oracle's documentation

Tried to modify the Rest API with several permutations,
All are ending with the same message "Illegal character in path at index"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to list the buckets, you have the wrong endpoint. There's no information in the docs indicating the version `20160918` should be passed in the uri.

The correct uri should be

`https://objectstorage.{{MYREGION}}.oraclecloud.com/n/{{TENANCY}}/b/?compartmentId={{compartmentId}}`

*src: https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/api/#/en/objectstorage/20160918/Bucket/ListBuckets*

Comment: Hey Jeremy,
Thanks for the response.
I have the Compartment ID and Tenancy ID(I guess I should use the ocid and not the Compartment name/Tenancy name itself, right?
In my case they are identical, (Compartment = Tenancy) is that OK?

That's the new URL that I ran and got the same error message "Illegal character in path at index" with the lase index in the end.
(The ocid was shorten before I've uploaded it to StackOverflow . . .)

https://objectstorage.{{Region}}.oraclecloud.com/n/ocid1.tenancy..0my/b/?compartmentId=ocid1.tenancy..0my

Comment: is your `tenacy` the same as your `namespaceName`?  The docs indicate the namespace is part of the uri and the `compartmentId` is a required query param.